# Use variable from loop in code behind to populate table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, repeater

This is what I have on my **aspx** page

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Line#</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Status</th>
   <%-- Make this column visible only for a certain condition--%>
        <th>Inventory</th>
   <%----%>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:repeater id="shoppingcartlines" runat="server">
                <itemtemplate>
                      <tr>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LineNo") %></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ItemName")%></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Quantity")%></td>
            <td><%= StatusVal  %></td>
            <td><%= InvVal  %></td>
                     </tr>
               </itemtemplate>
        </asp:repeater> 
    </tbody>
```

This is what I have in my **aspx.cs** page ( code-behind )

```
foreach ()
{
 StatusVal = loopdetail.Status; // string
 InvVal = loopdetail.InvVal; // string

}
```

Problem 1 :
Desired output for a particular loop :

```
Status Inv

False   10
True    20
```

Output now :

```
Status  Inv

 True    20
 True    20
```

The StatusVal variable is displaying the last grabbed value from the loop. I want them to display it line by line as shown above.

I am doing this on the page load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   foreach (ItemDetail loopdetail in Custom.ItemDetails)
            {
                // StatusVal and InvVal are public strings
                StatusVal = loopdetail.Status; // string
                InvVal = loopdetail.InvVal; // string

            }
  }
```

Problem 2 :

I want to display the Inventory Column only if it matches a certain condition. Should I be changing my aspx file or aspx.cs ?

Comment: what is StatusVal.. what's its type..? also perhaps you are wanting to create a `List<StatusVal>`can you post all relevant code please

Comment: You need to add those extra values to the object that is bound to repeater, and use data bound event to show/hide required columns.

Comment: @MethodMan StatusVal is a string . The loop seems to work just fine . I think the fact my aspx code has <td><%= StatusVal  %></td> , it's only taking the last initialized value.

Comment: @ArindamNayak That's a separate dataset which is giving values to the  other 3 fields. Can I add columns and values to a dataset ?

Comment: Yea you can add values, or take required datatable from that and add some columns and row values to them

Comment: I do not think your loop is working fine.. and also please state what event the code is in, in regards to your .cs file.. is this being performed on the `OnDataBound` event..? please once again show all relevant code that pertains to your existing issue.. looks like your `for loop` needs to be a foreach loop do you know how to iterate through a repeater..? here is an example 
`foreach (RepeaterItem  in shoppingcartlines.Items)` then do something

Comment: @MethodMan , I debugged my code and the loop seems to give me the values alright . I am building the table in Page_Load .

Comment: well can't really determine what you are or are not doing correctly without you posting relevant code.. if it's in the `Page_Load` then show that event handler / code.. come on now.. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**
This is how *I* know how to do it:

```
Datatable dt = new Datatable();
dt.Columns.Add("StatusVal", typeof(bool));
dt.Columns.Add("InvVal", typeof(string));

foreach()
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[2]{loopdetail.Status, loopdetail.InvVal});
}

shoppingcartlines.DataSource = dt;
shoppingcartlines.DataBind();
```

Maybe this solution is obvious to you and there are limitations to you being able to do this, just thought I would mention it.

**Problem 2:**

Given whatever condition you want to use in order to determine visibility, one thing you could do is:

```
protected void shoppingcartlines_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    HtmlTableCell td = (HtmlTableCell)item.FindControl("idOfTdYouWantToHide");

    if (iWantToDisplay)
    {
        td.Visible = true;
        // if that doesn't work, just do:
        //    td.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
}
```

I should also state that the property, "OnItemDataBound", should be added to your repeater, and reference the method above:

```
OnItemDataBound="shoppingcartlines_ItemDataBound"
```

Lastly, don't forget to add add

```
<%= Bind("StatusVal") %>
```

and

```
<%= Bind("InvVal") %>
```

to your td elements.

Comment: so do I make a different table just for the 2 columns ? and then bind it to the new datasource ?

Comment: You should be able to keep it in the same table. Just add <%= Bind("StatusVal") %> and <%= Bind("InvVal") %>to the td elements.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?